# UISplitviewController First Show MasterViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to use splitview controller in my app.But when I run the app it's going to detailviewcontroller in portrait mode iphone.

So I want to open first masterviewcontroller. So what should I do ?

Comment: Want to share your code...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ovverride the following in your delegate:

```
- (UIViewController *)primaryViewControllerForCollapsingSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
```

When this is called, return the controller you want to be shown. According to the docs you should also implement the other direction:

```
- (UIViewController *)primaryViewControllerForExpandingSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/primaryViewControllerForCollapsingSplitViewController:

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html) you can set the `preferredDisplayMode`

```
self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay
```